# How can I change colors of series of survival plot in highcharter?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to change the colors of the **survival plot** series in highcharter in R.
**hc_colors** doesn't work. I can only change the color of all lines using lineColor argument with **hc_plotOptions**.

```
library('survival')
library('highcharter')
leukemia.surv <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)

# this doesn't work, the lines are in default colors
highcharter::hchart(leukemia.surv)%>%
  hc_colors(c("#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF"))

# this results with all lines in blue
highcharter::hchart(leukemia.surv)%>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(lineColor = "blue"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
highchart()%>%
  hc_add_series(data=data.frame(Maintained =round(c(1,leukemia.surv$surv[1:10])*100,2) ,
                                Maintained.time = c(0,leukemia.surv$time[1:10])),
                hcaes(y = Maintained, x = Maintained.time),
                type="line",
                name="Maintained",
                color="#0073C2FF")%>%
  hc_add_series(data=data.frame(Nonmaintained =round(c(1,leukemia.surv$surv[11:20])*100,2),
                                Nonmaintained.time = c(0,leukemia.surv$time[11:20])),
                hcaes(y = Nonmaintained, x = Nonmaintained.time),
                type="line",
                name="Nonmaintained",
                color="#EFC000FF")%>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Survival rate"),
           max=100,
           labels=list(format="{value:,f}"))%>%
  hc_xAxis(title=list(text="Time"))
```

will give you:
[image: a picture with maintained and Nonmaintained as series 1 and 2]

Problem is that it is totally unclear (at least to me) what you are acutally calling from `leukemia.surv`. For colors to work, I found `hc_add_series` very usefull. Note that I rounded the values after multiplying them with 100 and labled the axis.